# For loop and vectors causing trouble

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector

I am trying to create a for loop that runs through a vector, pushes something into a queue, updates all appropriate elements of the struct of the vector and then loops again until the vector is empty.

The problem I am having is that the function to run through my for loop does not seem to be updating my vector elements, I am getting the same output even though I know it should be changing.

Here is the link to a gist of the project https://gist.github.com/sgodfrey321/6cffd85896432b2942aa , it just has a lot of filler, I had to input alot of stuff by hand so it is kinda messy.

So to start with I pass my vector to the function in a while loop

```
void queueNodes(vector<vertex>& list, queue<vertex>& q);
```

as such

```
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 11) {
    queueNodes(nodes, q);
    counter++;
}
```

the while loop is to make sure that I run through the vector enough times. Now in the function I check to see if incomingEdges of the struct is 0 and if it is I push it into the queue and update the next door incomingEdges:

```
void queueNodes(vector<vertex>& nodes, queue<vertex>& q) {
for (auto i : nodes) {
    cout << endl << i.vertexName << "             ";
    if (i.incomingEdges == 0) {
        i.nextDoorTop->incomingEdges--;
        i.nextDoorMiddle->incomingEdges--;
        i.nextDoorBottom->incomingEdges--;
        q.push(i);
        cout << "foo";
    } else {
        cout << "bar";
    }
}
```

Now I would expect that when I use the function again with the updated vector I would see a change in output as updating the next door incomingEdges would cause some to trigger the condition I am looking for. I have written outputs that show the next door incomingEdges are in fact decreasing however I can not seem to use the updated vector in the function call.

Do I need to return the vector somehow? I am sure that I am calling the function incorrectly, but does anyone have any ideas?

Thank You
edit: forgot to pass by reference the queue!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

struct vertex {
char vertexName;
int incomingEdges;
vertex* nextDoorTop;
vertex* nextDoorMiddle;
vertex* nextDoorBottom;
};
void queueNodes(vector<vertex>& nodes);

int main() {
vertex s, A, G, D, B, H, E, C, I, F, t;
s.vertexName = 's';
s.incomingEdges = 0;
s.nextDoorTop = &A;
s.nextDoorMiddle = &D;
s.nextDoorBottom = &G;
A.vertexName = 'A';
A.incomingEdges = 2;
A.nextDoorTop = &B;
A.nextDoorMiddle = &E;
G.vertexName = 'G';
G.incomingEdges = 1;
G.nextDoorTop = &D;
G.nextDoorMiddle = &E;
G.nextDoorBottom = &H;
D.vertexName = 'D';
D.incomingEdges = 2;
D.nextDoorMiddle = &E;
B.vertexName = 'B';
B.incomingEdges = 1;
B.nextDoorTop = &C;
H.vertexName = 'H';
H.incomingEdges = 1;
H.nextDoorTop = &E;
H.nextDoorMiddle = &I;
E.vertexName = 'E';
E.incomingEdges = 4;
E.nextDoorTop = &C;
E.nextDoorMiddle = &F;
E.nextDoorBottom = &I;
C.vertexName = 'C';
C.incomingEdges = 3;
C.nextDoorMiddle = &t;
I.vertexName = 'I';
I.incomingEdges = 2;
I.nextDoorTop = &F;
I.nextDoorMiddle = &t;
F.vertexName = 'F';
F.incomingEdges = 2;
F.nextDoorMiddle = &t;
t.vertexName = 't';
t.incomingEdges = 3;

vector<vertex> nodes { s, A, G, D, B, H, E, C, I, F, t };
cout << "Vertex Name: " << " Number Of Edges: " << endl;
for (auto i : nodes) {
    cout << i.vertexName << "         " << i.incomingEdges << "                 "
            << endl;
}
int counter = 0;
while (counter < 11) {
    queueNodes(nodes);
    counter++;
}
return 0;
}
void queueNodes(vector<vertex>& nodes) {
for (auto& i : nodes) {
    cout << endl << i.vertexName << "             ";
    if (i.incomingEdges == 0) {
        i.nextDoorTop->incomingEdges--;
        i.nextDoorMiddle->incomingEdges--;
        i.nextDoorBottom->incomingEdges--;
        cout << "foo";
    } else {
        cout << "bar";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `for (auto i : nodes)` gives you a copy of the elements. Try `for (auto& i : nodes)` if you want to modify the vector's elements.

Comment: I tried that, no dice.

Comment: Any chance of a [minimal complete example](http://www.sscce.org)?

Comment: Note also that you will have copy of `vertex` inside the `queue`..

Comment: I put up a SSCCE on gisthub @Beta, I am working with certain data that I had to input by hand so I didn't want to make a mess on this page. The link is https://gist.github.com/sgodfrey321/6cffd85896432b2942aa

Comment: And @Jarod42, I just straight up deleted the queue from the code and I am still having the problem

Comment: Could you add your current test-code snippet (without the queue and with the & after auto) to the end of your post above?

Comment: `nodes` contains a copy of `s`, `A`, `G`, ... So you may change `nodes` type to `std::vector<vertex*>`. And at least `D.nextDoorTop` is uninitialized.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in the `queueNodes` function. Look into how you're initializing the data structure.

Comment: I've done some changes: https://ideone.com/qUeUXM I don't think it does what you want, but the `vertex` are modified.